# how sync service whit onlocationchanged to frament?

Tags: android, service, android-fragments, gps

i have a main activity whit navigation drawer (whit frame layout)

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
    FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        MapFragment mapFragment= new MapFragment();

        /**
        // Creating a Bundle object
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
        data.putInt("position", position);

        // Setting the position to the fragment
        mapFragment.setArguments(data);


        // Creating a fragment transaction
        ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        */

        // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mapFragment);
        ft.commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        GpsDatiFragment gpsFragment= new GpsDatiFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,gpsFragment);
        ft.commit();
        break;
    case 2:
        AltroFragment altroFragment= new AltroFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, altroFragment);
        ft.commit();
        break;
    case 3: 
        finish();
    default:
        break;

    }
```

here all ok, In One fragment there is the map and in another there is a details of gps and location (altitude, latitude, time to fix ecc)....then i have create a service that implement location listener and i'll want that it send info of onlocationchanded and gpsstatus to fragment 1 (map whit location) and 2 (altitude speed latitude time to fix) but i dont know how to do.....how sync the info for both fragment??? thanks

edit:

this is my service

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
String provider;
Criteria criteria;


// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 400; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
        //Criteria criteria= new Criteria();
        //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        //provider= locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        //location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

        if (isGPSEnabled){
        if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            }
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        }

        }else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
/*
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}*/

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    getLocation();
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

and this is my fragment for map:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment  {

GoogleMap mapView;
Intent intent;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
Location location ;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    // create class object
    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), GPSTracker.class)); 

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater mInflater, ViewGroup arg1,
        Bundle arg2) {
    return super.onCreateView(mInflater, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public void onInflate(Activity arg0, AttributeSet arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    super.onInflate(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    

    gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

    // check if GPS enabled     
        //location = gps.getLocation();     
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        mapView = getMap();
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.draggable(true);
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        mapView.addMarker(markerOptions);

        // \n is for new line
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        // gps.showSettingsAlert();



}
```

}

this is fragment for deatils:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);



    longitudeField= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    altitudine= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    precisione= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    speed= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    timeFix= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    satFixed= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    elencoSat= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    latitudeField= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    gps= new GPSTracker(getActivity());
            update();
       return rootView;
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //update();
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}
```

public void update(){

```
location = gps.getLocation();
lat= location.getLatitude();
lng= location.getLongitude();
pre= (int) location.getAccuracy();
vel= location.getSpeed();
latitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
//altitudine.setText(String.valueOf(alt)+" metri");
precisione.setText(String.valueOf(pre)+" metri");
speed.setText(String.valueOf(vel)+" km/h");
```

}

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new fragment every time `selectItem()` method is called. Instead of doing that you should rather use method `findFragmentByTag()` to obtain fragment you created earlier and create new one only if there is no such fragment.

Then you can simply store in your activity the variable for each fragment and pass required information to selected fragments.

Comment: i added new datails of my class